# Why my Edit Collider in Unity2D has no point to adjust size?

Tags: unity

Why when I clicked to Edit Collider of Box Collider 2D component, is not showing points for me resize the collide box?

[image]

Comment: Same happens in other scenes or objects? unity version?

Comment: Yes, this situation exist with any scenes and objects. I'm using Unity 5.4.0f3

Comment: are you trying to edit collider in scene view or game view? image shows it's zoom-able game view. you have to edit on scene view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit collider in the Scene view instead of trying it in Game view.

Image shows you are trying it in zoom-able game view.